# when I add post I want to show updated page list

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to scroll position when I added post

Here's a code

I think I use scrolltoPostion function but before using this I have to define RecyclerView but in this class I have a problem with defining RecyclerView because I don't know what is a right variable to add to Recycler view ex)Recyclerview rv; rv=???

```
private void addPost(Post post) {

    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Posts").push();


    // get post unique ID and upadte post key
    String key = myRef.getKey();
    post.setPostKey(key);
    // add post data to firebase database

    myRef.setValue(post).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {

            popupClickProgress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            popupAddBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            // illegal 오류 해결 수정
            if(popAddPost!=null&&popAddPost.isShowing()){
                popAddPost.dismiss();
            }
            RecyclerView rv;
            rv.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(0);

        }
    });

}
```

but I can't use RecyclerView in this class. then how can I fix this? in other class I used Recycler View
here's a code

```
RecyclerView postRecyclerView ;
PostAdapter postAdapter;
FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
DatabaseReference databaseReference;
List<Post> postList;


public HomeFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static HomeFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
}



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    LinearLayoutManager lin = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    lin.setStackFromEnd(true);
    lin.setReverseLayout(true);
    View fragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    postRecyclerView = fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.postRV);
    postRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(lin);
    postRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Posts");
    return fragmentView;
}
```

I think maybe I use this postRecyclerView variable, or any other solutions here? I'm beginner so please give me hints.

Comment: yes use postRevyvlerView to scrool down

Comment: Then I import postRecylerView from fragment class to Home(first code) class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so from my understanding you want to update the recycler view as you add a new item to that list (array I suppose). So use an updater function for that. You can define the recycler view to whatever you want, rv works just fine. You can use Live Data to work with the data you are feeding to the recycler view. Check this out and see if it helps you in some way.
https://medium.com/@atifmukhtar/recycler-view-with-mvvm-livedata-a1fd062d2280